# Ionic - Runtime Error this.fba.logEvent(...).then is not a function

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-analytics

I am using Ionic and Firebase. I have created firebase project, clicked on icon to "add fire to your android app" and followed the steps.

Foll. is code on my html page:

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  Firebase Analytics
  <p>
    Click the button to log a custom event
  </p>
  <button ion-button full (click)="logClick()">Log event</button>
</ion-content>
```

Below code is on the ts of this page:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { EventLoggerProvider } from '../../providers/event-logger/event-logger';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public logger: EventLoggerProvider) {
  }

  logClick() {
    this.logger.logButton('homeButton',{ pram: "paramValue" })
}
}
```

Foll. code is in the provider:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseAnalytics } from '@ionic-native/firebase-analytics';

@Injectable()
export class EventLoggerProvider {

  constructor(public fba: FirebaseAnalytics) {
    console.log('Hello EventLoggerProvider Provider');
  }

  logButton(name:string,value:any){
    this.fba.logEvent(name, { pram:value })
    .then((res: any) => {console.log(res);})
    .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
  }
}
```

I ran "ionic cordova run android" and launched the app on mobile device and everything seems to be OK. However, when I do "ionic serve", the page loads OK in the browser, but when I click the button, what could have caused it to give the foll. error?

> Ionic - Runtime Error this.fba.logEvent(...).then is not a function

[image: runtime error]

Comment: kindly please share your ts file, this seems wrong to me `this.fba.logEvent` , I think your missing `analytics` it's mostly something like this `firebase.analytics.logEvent("MyClickEvent", { Action: "test" })`

Comment: Edited the question and included all the code, note that is used in the provider correctly. Also note there is no such error on mobile device. The error in only in browser (ionic serve)

Comment: Cordova platform is not available in ionic serve.. The plugins dont work. You can check for platform before calling the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now its more clear after seing the code.

`import { FirebaseAnalytics } from '@ionic-native/firebase-analytics';`

`@ionic-native` functions only work on the real device or simulator. Otherwise, it will give an error.

Comment: I am getting same error while inspecting app on native device. Can you guess where the error should be then?
The only difference is i imported FirebaseAnalytics from '@ionic-native/firebase-analytics/ngx' beacause without ngx I am getting "Cannot find name 'FirebaseAnalytics'."
And I call logEvent method using "EventLoggerService" that I defined